# VS2010 Environment Variables w/ Intel Fortran

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, fortran, intel-fortran

I'm using a VS2010 C++/Intel Fortran XE2011 mixed environment on Windows 7.

I have a VS2010 Solution with both C++ and Fortran Projects. In the C++ Projects, the project file successfully resolves VS Environment variables, such as $(Platform) and $(ProjectDir). However, the Fortran project does not successfully resolves those and through's compilation errors.

A colleague of mine sitting next to me doesn't have any issue with the exact same Solution/Project files - so we think it has to do with Installation or Software Settings, but we've found nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't get a satisfactory answer here it would be worth searching / asking on the intel dev-zone forums for IVF on windows here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows  -- actually, looking up that URL I see you've already posted there.

Comment: Thanks Casey, I did. I've used that before, but found this forum to be much more searchable and that forum full with more experience fortran users. Thanks!